# Cannot pass variable from text box

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

On the line

```
const string subject = "hello" + textBox1.Text;
```

it doesn't print the value of textBox1.Text but i print the word "textBox1.Text". How can I fix it?

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("samuimark@gmail.com", "samui mail");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("teeramail@gmail.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "t429";
const string subject = "hello" + textBox1.Text  ;
const string body = "you have a mail";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Tried removing const?    string subject = "hello" + textBox1.Text  ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
const string subject = "hello" + textBox1.Text  ;
```

Use

```
string subject = "hello" + textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Other guys said the same thing technically. But according to type of question I realized copy/paste matters here. Happy it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

textBox1.Text is not constant expression. assing its value to string not const string

```
string subject = "hello" + textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using

```
Subject = subject,
Body = body
```

I recommend you to change it too like

```
Subject = subject.Text,
Body = body.Text
```

Just change "subject.Text" and "body.Text" to whatever your text boxes are named
But you must keep the .Text